# After providing domain name and ip address in extra hosts in my gitlab runner my pipeline failed

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd, gitlab-runner

After providing domain name and ip address in extra hosts in my gitlab runner config.toml my pipeline error shows fatal error unable to access https:// : failed to connect to  port 443 : operation timed out

Comment: And I also found that the token in config.toml and I provided token aren't same!

Comment: How do I change the token in config.toml and run the runner in normal condition